# Google GeoCharts Data not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, google-api

So here is the problem in attached code. I have a GeoCharts div with a form div next to it, in the background there are multiple CSV documents that are managing the data. The goal is to load the data by the current selection of filters in the form div when the `#showButton` is pressed.

So when the page is loaded the 'general' CSV document is loaded to represent the data and when the user wants to see data by the current filters selection the other CSV document is loaded when the user presses `#showButton`. But the thing is that that happens only when the `#showButton` is pressed twice with nothing changing in the filters the second times.

Everything else like the `displayMode` (markers) variable that is passed to the function and the colorForSex variable gets loaded and applied to the GeoCharts div but the CSV file and all the data gets loaded only the second time that the button is pressed (again - without changing the filters the second time it is pressed).

```
/*

Coded by : Roland Stojkoski;

Contact : roland.roland.roli@gmail.com

*/



/* CSV handling - START */

var processedData = [];

var newData = [];

var region = $('select[name="region"] option:selected').val();
var sex = $('select[name="sex"] option:selected').val();
var age = $('select[name="age"] option:selected').val();
var permOrNot = $('select[name="permOrNot"] option:selected').val();
var permSelect = $('select[name="permSelect"] option:selected').val();

getFile('csv/Residence_All.csv');


/* CSV handling - END */

var chart;
var data;

$(document).ready(function(){   

    /* Google Charts */

    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyBHggo3wq70fGWUJwvCCHNnQm0E4R2G_l8 ',
        'callback': drawRegionsMap
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

    function drawRegionsMap() {
        region = $('select[name="region"] option:selected').val();
        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(processedData);

        var options = {
            region: region,
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '100%' },
            colorAxis: {colors: ['#ddd','#ff1a1a']},
            datalessRegionColor: 'white',
            displayMode: 'markers',
            legend: {
                numberFormat: '.##',
                textStyle: {
                    fontName: 'Nunito Sans',
                    color: '#ff1a1a',
                    fontSize: 14,
                }
            }   
        };

        chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }


    $('#showButton').click(function(){
        if($('select[name="region"] option:selected').val() === 'world' && $('select[name="sex"] option:selected').val() === 'all' && $('select[name="age"] option:selected').val() === 'all' ){
            loadData('csv/Origin_All.csv', '#a80000', 'regions');
        }else if ($('select[name="region"] option:selected').val() === 'world' && $('select[name="sex"] option:selected').val() === 'female'){
            loadData('csv/Origin_Sex_Female.csv', '#ff9933', 'regions');
        }else if ($('select[name="region"] option:selected').val() === 'CH'){
            loadData('csv/Residence_All.csv', '#a80000', 'text');
        }
    });

    $('select').change(function(){
        if($('select[name="region"] option:selected').val() === 'world'){
            $('select[name="age"]').fadeIn();
            $('select[name="permOrNot"]').fadeOut();
            if($('select[name="sex"] option:selected').val() != 'all'){
                $('select[name="age"]').fadeOut();
            }else{
                $('select[name="age"]').fadeIn();
            }
            if($('select[name="age"] option:selected').val() != 'all'){
                $('select[name="sex"]').fadeOut();
            }else{
                $('select[name="sex"]').fadeIn();
            }
        }else if($('select[name="region"] option:selected').val() === 'CH'){
            $('select[name="age"]').fadeOut();
            $('select[name="permOrNot"]').fadeIn();
            if($('select[name="permOrNot"] option:selected').val() === 'perm'){
                $('select[name="permSelect"]').fadeIn();
            }else{
                $('select[name="permSelect"]').fadeOut();
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).scrollTop(0);

    $('#menu').velocity({
        top: 0
    }, 900);

    $('#content > p').velocity({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1500, 'linear');

    $('#categories').velocity({
        marginLeft: '2%'
    },900, 'linear');

    $('#chart_div').velocity({
        opacity: 1
    },900, 'linear');

    setTimeout(introAnimation, 800);

    function introAnimation() {


        $('#logo').velocity({
            opacity: 1
        }, 900, 'linear');

        $('nav > ul > li').velocity({
            opacity: 1
        }, 900, 'linear');

        $('#data').velocity({
            opacity: 1
        }, 900, 'linear');

        $('#social').velocity({
            opacity: 1
        }, 900, 'linear');

    }

    $('.facebook, .facebook > i').hover(function(){
        $('.facebook > i').css('color', '#3b5998');
    });

    $('.facebook').mouseout(function(){
        $('.facebook > i').css('color', '#ddd');
    });

    $('.facebook > i').mouseout(function(){
        $('.facebook > i').css('color', '#3b5998');
    });

    $('.twitter, .twitter > i').hover(function(){
        $('.twitter > i').css('color', '#1da1f2');
    });

    $('.twitter').mouseout(function(){
        $('.twitter > i').css('color', '#ddd');
    });

    $('.twitter > i').mouseout(function(){
        $('.twitter > i').css('color', '#1da1f2');
    });

    $('.googlePlus, .googlePlus > i').hover(function(){
        $('.googlePlus > i').css('color', '#e53935');
    });

    $('.googlePlus').mouseout(function(){
        $('.googlePlus > i').css('color', '#ddd');
    });

    $('.googlePlus > i').mouseout(function(){
        $('.googlePlus > i').css('color', '#e53935');
    });

    /* Show button - End */



});

function loadData(file, colorForSex, marker){

    var region = $('select[name="region"] option:selected').val();

    getFile(file);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(processedData);

    var options = {
        region: region,
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '100%' },
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#ddd', colorForSex]},
        datalessRegionColor: 'white',
        displayMode: marker,
        legend: {
            numberFormat: '.##',
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Verdana',
                color: '#ff1a1a',
                fontSize: 14
            }
        }   
    };

    chart.draw(data, options);
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function getFile(fileUrl){
    $.get(fileUrl+'?q='+Math.random(), function(data) {

            processedData = $.csv.toArrays(data);

            var j = 1;

            for (var i = 1; i < processedData.length; i++) {
                for(var k = 0; k < processedData[i][j].length; k++){
                    if(processedData[i][j].charAt(k) == ','){
                        processedData[i][j]=processedData[i][j].substring(0,k)+processedData[i][j].substring(k+1,processedData[i][j].length-1);
                    }
                }
                processedData[i][j] = parseFloat(processedData[i][j]);
            }

    }, 'text');

    return processedData;
}
```

And here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:900|Roboto:400,700"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <title>Facts About Migration | Home</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="velocity.ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Fav Icon -->

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/favIco/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="images/favIco/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favIco/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="images/favIco/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favIco/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="images/favIco/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/favIco/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <!-- Fav Icon - End -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="#"><img id="logoImg" src="images/logo.png"/></a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li class="navLi"><a class="nav" href="#" id="activeNav">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="navLi"><a class="nav" href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li class="navLi"><a class="nav" href="#">SPONSORS</a></li>
                <li class="navLi"><a class="nav" href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                <div id="socialDiv">
                    <li class="facebook social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="twitter social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="googlePlus social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mainApp">
        <main>
            <form name="categories" id="categories">
                <select name="region">
                    <option value="world" selected>Show All</option>
                    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                </select>
                <select name="sex">
                    <option value="all" selected>Sex (Both)</option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
                <select name="age">
                    <option value="all" selected>Age (All)</option>
                    <option value="0-14">0 - 14</option>
                    <option value="15-19">15 - 19</option>
                    <option value="20-39">20 - 39</option>
                    <option value="40-64">40 - 64</option>
                    <option value="65-79">65 - 79</option>
                    <option value="80+">80+</option>
                </select>
                <select name="permOrNot">
                    <option value="all">Permanent and Non permanent
Foreign residents</option>
                    <option value="perm">Permanent foreign resident population</option>
                    <option value="not">Non permanent
Foreign residents </option>
                </select>
                <select name="permSelect">
                    <option value="all">All Permanent foreign resident population</option>
                    <option value="short">Short-term residents (L)</option>
                    <option value="residents">Residents (B)</option>
                    <option value="settled">Settled (C)</option>
                </select>
                <input type="button" name="categoriesButton" id="showButton" value="SHOW ON MAP"/>
            </form>
            <div id="chart_div">

            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget ipsum ut urna convallis elementum. Etiam a fringilla felis. Pellentesque iaculis eu turpis et placerat. Maecenas posuere rutrum turpis, non cursus justo. Vivamus vestibulum tincidunt felis et elementum. Duis dapibus interdum leo quis euismod. Nulla ullamcorper elementum felis et malesuada. Integer pharetra sem vel fermentum gravida. Ut facilisis placerat pellentesque.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum maximus arcu non est luctus, sit amet pharetra lorem consectetur. Duis vitae risus ac metus sagittis gravida. Aenean vulputate magna ac leo feugiat ornare. Sed laoreet nulla vel nibh blandit, sed mollis elit placerat. Ut vel diam finibus, lacinia lectus id, iaculis nisi. Sed hendrerit dui risus, a dictum purus varius a. Curabitur congue, mi eget ullamcorper bibendum, odio nisi egestas nunc, venenatis rutrum magna ipsum ac purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="windowBox box1">

    </div>
    <footer>
        <a href="#">
        <div class="sponsors">
            <img src="images/logoExample.png"/>
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
        <div class="sponsors">
            <img src="images/logoExample.png"/>
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
        <div class="sponsors">
            <img src="images/logoExample.png"/>
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
        <div class="sponsors">
            <img src="images/logoExample.png"/>
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
        <div class="sponsors">
            <img src="images/logoExample.png"/>
        </div>
        </a>
    </footer>
    <div id="bottom">
        <ul id="bottomLeft">
            <li>Copyright &copy; 2017. All rights reserved.</li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="bottomRight">
                <a href="#" class="facebookFooter"><li class="facebookFooter"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square facebookFooter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
                <a href="#" class="twitterFooter"><li class="twitterFooter"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square twitterFooter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
                <a href="#" class="googlePlusFooter"><li class="googlePlusFooter"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square googlePlusFooter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add your html and csv data as well

Comment: @WilliamValhakis I have edited my original answer

Comment: @halfer I have edited my original answer

Comment: It's a little unclear what your core problem is. Could you expand on that, in the question again? You've said what happens, what do you actually want to happen? (There was some extra text in your additional material, maybe add that?)

Comment: @halfer here it is, I can not explain it more haha thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It was hiding in the ajax setup settings. The code at the start of the script file was enough to solve the problem - `$.ajaxSetup({async:false});`